# Interactive uk counties map in python dash application

Tags: python, maps, amcharts, plotly-dash, folium

I have spent ages trying to figure out a way of putting an interactive UK Counties map on a Python Dash app.

The map will show locations of tweets from the twitter developer api that I have in an sqlite database.

I've tried using Folium, but attempting to load counties from a massive GeoJSON file is a mess, and takes ages,and I can only find a GeoJSON file for English counties. I also need Scotland and Northern Ireland. I don't really want the map to be able to move, but I realise I might have to accept that as a consequence of zooming in or out. I just want the user to be able to click on a county and show twitter data in a separate part of the webpage. I would also like to put markers in the relevant county for tweets in my sqlite database that have location data. The user could then click on the marker and reveal the text of the tweet.

I know amcharts have an uk-counties.svg chart, but:
a) I can't fathom out how to embed this on a Dash webpage, and
b) if I do get it on a webpage, would I then be able to show location data, and if so, then how?

I've looked at MapBox, openstreetmap, and google maps, but they all seem overly complicated for what I'm trying to do.

Any help/suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You can get administrative areas for any country on [GADM](https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html) (choose UK as it inclues NI and Scotland). For lower zoom levels you can simplify the geometries so it will load quicker.

Comment: Thanks Ionut. But what’s the best way to pursue this? Could I do it with Folium? Any suggestions on how to go about all this are hugely appreciated.

Comment: I haven't used Folium but if the only issue is loading large GeoJSON files you should be able to take the shapefile data from GADM, simplify the geometries and export it to GeoJSON; [QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=simplify#simplify) can do all these tasks.

Comment: Thanks Ionut for your replies.  What would you suggest as a good way to display such a map on a website? What method would you use? Could you point me in the direction on a good tutorial?

Comment: I would use [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).

Comment: I have had a look at leaflet, but can I produce a webpage that uses python dash with leaflet? I don't just want a map, I want other stuff as well, with python doing the background work.

Comment: I don't have experience with "dash" but if it's a webpage I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to use Leaflet; and apparently there's [dash-leaflet](https://pypi.org/project/dash-leaflet/).